# Uppercase variable scope in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, filtering

If for example I used this line to generate a model:

```
bin/rails generate model Item Collection:references
```

Then it will generate this kind of migration with the uppercase reference variable:

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.references :Collection, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And this generates a Collection_id field in the table with the uppercase.

The problem is I want now to add a Scope, to filter Items by Collection_id from the controller:

So I created this scope in the Item's model 
`scope :collection_id, -> (Collection_id) { where collection_id: Collection_id }`

But when I call it in the controller with:
@items = Item.collection_id(@user.Collection_id)

It crashes with:

> formal argument cannot be a constant scope :collection_id, ->
>   (Collection_id) { where collection_id: Collection_id } ^

I read in the scope the variable cannot be an uppercase variable but since the migration is creating them by default that way I dont know if this is intended or I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your scope to:

```
scope :collection_id, -> (collection_id) { where collection_id: collection_id }
```

All variables in the ruby start a with capital letter is a constant. 
I suggest you to fix it:

First rollback migration:

```
bin/rake db:rollback
```

Destroy model:

```
bin/rails destroy model Item Collection:references
```

Generate model with normal letter case:

```
bin/rails generate model Item collection:references
```

That's it.

Read this [`Ruby Variables, Constants and Literals`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_variables.htm)

Comment: It would be better to add some explanation about using ruby constant as scope argument to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you capitalise Collection when generating the model? Rails does things a certain way to provide alot of services for you to use. If you flout its convention you will always be fighting rails.

I would rollback the migration and reverse the model gneration. Then run it again but do not capitalise the references and everything should work as expected. Make sure you rollback before you

```
rails destroy model Item
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem